Rank of the composition of 2 endomorphisms.

Let $E,F,G$ be  finite dimensional vector spaces and $f \in L(E,F)$ ; $g \in L(F,G)$.
Prove that $$\operatorname{rank}(g\circ f) =\operatorname{rank}(g) \iff F = \operatorname{Im}(f) + \operatorname{ker}(g)$$

I know that $\operatorname{rank}(g \circ f)=\operatorname{rank}(g)$ implies that $f$ is surjective, wouldn't that mean that $F = \operatorname{Im}(f)?$ Where did $\operatorname{ker}(g)$ come from.

anything that $g$ maps to $0$ is already covered since $0 \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$, so the kernel of $g$ does not have to be hit by $f$.

If $g$ is the zero map, then so is $g \circ f$, so that the rank of both $g \circ f$ and $g$ is zero, but of course $f$ need not be surjective.

Hint: the image of $g \circ f$ is contained in the image of $g$, so that the two ranks are equal iff for every $x \in F$ there is $y \in Im(f)$ such that $g(x) = g(y)$, that is $g(x - y) = 0$...

"$\Leftarrow$":  In this case $$\operatorname{Im}(g) = g(F) = g(\operatorname{Im}(f)) + g(\ker(g)) = g(f(E)) + g(\ker(g)) = (g\circ f) (E) + \{0\} =\operatorname{Im}(g\circ f).$$ The rank is just the dimension of the image, so the implication follows.
"$\Rightarrow$":
We know that $g(f(E)) \leq g(F)$ as linear subspaces. Since
$$ \operatorname{dim}(g(f(E)) = \operatorname{rk} (g\circ f) =\operatorname{rk}(g) = \operatorname{dim}(g(F))$$ and both subspaces are finite dimensional,
$$g(f(E)) = g(F)$$
Take some $v\in F$. Then
$$g(f(E)) + \mathbb{K}g(v) = g(F) + \mathbb{K}g(v) = g(F) = g(f(E)),$$ which implies $$g(v) \in \operatorname{Im}(g\circ f),$$ so
$$g(v) = g(f(w))$$ for some $w \in E$. But then by linearity
$$g(v-f(w)) = 0,$$ so
$$v -f(w) \in \ker(g),$$ or in other words
$$v \in f(w) + \ker(g) \subset \operatorname{Im}(f) + \ker(g).$$
